# Problem with Tomcat9 Context's docBase attribute

Tags: java, web, tomcat

I am new to Tomcat deployment.

I found in Tomcat's document and it says this about `<Context>` tag's `docBase` attribute:

> The value of this field must not be set unless the Context element is defined in server.xml or the docBase is not located under the Host's appBase.

Here is my problem:

1. I create a `<Host>` tag inside server.xml and set `appBase="C:/xxx/"`
2. create a xml file named `ROOT.xml` inside `C:/xxx/` and add `<Context docBase="../yyy" />`
3. put index.html inside `C:/yyy/`

Why is it doesn't work when I try to browser `localhost:8080/` ?

Doesn't it supposed to show the `index.html` inside `C:/yyy` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**

When you add `appBase="C:/xxx"` to `server.xml`, that means all your web appplications will be found in that directory. At that point you cannot then have a specific web app which defines its own redirection to another directory (a custom `docBase`) *from within its own web application location*. At that point, its `docBase` location has already been set to be the `appBase` directory.

**A Different Approach**

The `ROOT.xml` file that you created *can* be used to point to a location which is different from the `appBase` - but you cannot place that file inside the `appBase` directory (as noted above).

Instead you have to place it in `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/` as described in this [documentation page](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/context.html#Defining_a_context).

So, for me, that would be:

```
C:\tomcat_9_test\conf\Catalina\localhost\ROOT.xml
```

And its contents would simply be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="C:/yyy" />
```

Because this is *outside* of the `docBase`, this *specific* application can have a different location from all the other web applications in `docBase`.

Now, your `C:\yyyy\index.html` file will be served at `http://localhost:8080/`, as expected.

**A Note on `context.xml`**

What if you do not use this `ROOT.xml` file at all, but instead you create a `ROOT` folder in `C:\xxx` and then create a `META-INF` folder there, containing a `context.xml` file?

You could define `<Context docBase="../yyy" />` in there.  But it would be ignored (again, because the `docBase` is already set).